# Novice User - Website Design

Tags: database, web

I have created a simple website but I need to store and extract files such as PowerPoint and Word files. Ive never created a database for a website before so can anyone suggest a simple database to use and maybe a tutorial to take me through it?

Comment: What platform and language are you using? Without such details, any recommendation is done blindly.

Comment: If you are only supplying files on a web site you have no need for a DB; put the files in a folder and put links on a page. However, if you are looking for file searching, user account management etc you are much better off finding a framework to give you all that.

Comment: Im workin off a mac. I experimented and set up a database using Sequel Pro and MAMP. I want to use the database to store and retrieve files just, but would it be better if to just store the files online like Tony suggested and use Lucene to find and retrieve these files as necessary (rather than using a db)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DB for a website should be no different than any other DB. The DB is independent of the front end (web, client app, etc.).

Avoid a pre-made database. Let the nature of the data decide the tables.